# CSS Linear Gradient Won't Work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a web page, and i'm trying to make the background be a gradient. this is my css code:

```
body {
  background-color: linear-gradient(#222222, #663300);
}
```

Why is my background plain white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `linear-gradient`(or any CSS gradient) should be defined with `background-image`, not `background-color`:

> Gradients are defined as CSS  data types; they can be used only where an image data type is required. For this reason, linear-gradient won't work on background-color and other properties requesting `<color>`.
>   <sub>[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)</sub>

```
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#222222, #663300);
}
```

Or:

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(#222222, #663300);
}
```

[JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/erjz1evo/)